# Use Services module to send email?

Tags: 7, emails, services

I have a non-Drupal site that has a sign-up form. I'm using the Services module to submit user creation requests via ajax. This works very well. Now I need to add a secondary action that will send a custom email after the user is created. Is there any way to accomplish this? There doesn't seem to be a resource for sending mail.

Comment: `hook_user_insert()`?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. I'm looking for a way to do this via ajax, not a custom module.

Comment: Well you could implement the above hook in a custom module to send the email when a user registers (through services module-handled request).